# Decomposing a entry-wise positive positive-semidefinite matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $\mathbf{A}$ be a symmetric $n\times n$ positive semi-definite matrix and also such that each of its entry is positive. Does $\mathbf{A}$ have a decomposition of the form
\begin{align}
\mathbf{A} \,=\,\sum_{i=1}^{i=k}\mathbf{y}_i\mathbf{y}_i^T
\end{align}
where each vector $\mathbf{y}$ is also entry-wise positive and $k\leq n$.

Comment: now asked, and answered in the negative, at https://mathoverflow.net/q/342488/11260